# Simulate a Location While in Instruments

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

How do I profile the processing of location information while running instruments?

If I have a GPX file running when I start instruments, the app gets restarted.

If I don't have the GPX file running, select location is grayed out when I am running instruments.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this in the meantime?

Comment: None--------------------- .

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll probably resort to using a subclass of `CLLocationManager` at runtime based on flag set in the Profile build scheme. I imagine something like that might work

Comment: Still a problem, 8 years later.